# Codeigniter Group By Returning Only First Row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a reservation module in codeigniter wherein I limit users to reserve the clubhouse for only 2 hours a day. I am currently creating a validation in codeigniter to limit their reservation. What I did was to select all the reservations, and group them by the rows having the same date in order to properly limit them. The problem is that the model I created is only returning 1 row, and not all the results. This means that my counter is just being changed by only one row, which I expect that all rows should affect the counter. 
Below is my database table:

[image]

Basically, the second row isn't supposed to be inserted in the database because user '20130123' already has used up his maximum reservation for the day which is two hours. I provided the validation check below on checking whether the user has used up two hours of reservation, and my logic here is that I just subtract the reservation end with the reservation start. Using the table above just as an example and for my explanation, my problem is that in my model, the counter's value becomes only "2" because it only reads the first row (8 - 6 = 2), instead of "3" (result of the first row which is 2, then add the result of second row which is 1 :  [(8-6) + (9-8)])

To sum it up, my problem lies on the counter's value, because it is only being added by the first row the query reads.

Here's my code.

Model:

```
function check_twohours_clubhouse()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('clubhouse_reservation')->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'))->group_by('reservation_date')->having('count(reservation_date) > 1')->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $ctr = '0';
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $totalhour = $row->reservation_end - $row->reservation_start; // subtract reservation start to reservation end to get the number of hours
            $ctr = $ctr + $totalhour;
        }

        $ctr = $ctr + ($this->input->post('reserveend') - $this->input->post('reservestart')); // add the selected "add reservation" hours to the counter 

        if($ctr > 2) // counter > 2 hours limit
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function create_reservation_clubhouse()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">','</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('datepick', 'Date', 'required|no_olddate');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('reservestart', 'Reservation Start', 'required|hourselection|unique_reserve_clubhouse|max_twohours');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->template->load('user_template', 'view_userreservation_addclubhouse');
    }
    else
    {
        if($this->model_reservation_user->check_twohours_courtone())
        {
            if($query = $this->model_reservation_user->create_reservation_clubhouse())
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('reservefeedback', 'You have successfully reserved a date for the Clubhouse. Please wait for the administrators to accept your reservation.');
                redirect('user_reservation/clubhouse');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('reservefail', 'You cannot reserve more than two hours of Clubhouse per day.');
                redirect('user_reservation/clubhouse');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls include some sample data, provide the SQL query that CI generates out of the code, the data the query returns and the data you would like the query to return based on your sample data.

Comment: I added an explanation above with the database table. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate all this in sql using [time_to_sec()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) and [timediff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) functions:

```
select reservation_date, sum(time_to_sec(timediff(reserveend, reservestart)) / 3600 as reserved_hours
from clubhouse_reservation
where username =...
group by reservation_date
having count(*)>1 --although it is not clear to me why you have this restriction
```

The above query would sum up for a given user per reservation date, the hours for which the clubhouse is reserved (3600 = number of secs in an hour).

In your php code you only need to check if the `reserved_hours` in the resultset is >2 or not.

I'm not really an expert with CI, therefore I can't really tell how to convert the above sql to CI. But I'm afraid that you have to use raw sql because of the way it sums the time.

Comment: Haven't tried this yet, but will the timediff work since my reserveend and reservestart values are just integers?